# Ansible Copy module & become - Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, ansible

I am running an ansible script on `localhost` to copy a folder to another location.
However,

```
- name: Copy Network
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  copy:
    src: /d/
    dest: "/dest/d/"
    mode: 0644
  tags: [network]
```

is giving me `[Errno 13] Permission denied: b'd/f1'`. I was expecting `become_user` will make the command execute as root, didn't work.
The permission of this file is `0600(root:root)`.

Can you please give me pointers to get access to this file to copy it using ansible?

**Note:**

- `sudo ansible-playbook p.yml` works perfectly however, I don't want to use `sudo` with ansible command if it's not required and ansible has a trick for it.
- `command: cp -r /d/ /dest/d/` works without appending `sudo` to the ansible command (`ansible-playbook p.yml`). However, I don't want to use `command` if I can help it because of idempotence & `copy` module has `mode` option required for the task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: If you can escalate the privilege to root on localhost master the solution is to set `remote_src: true` (credit @ivandov)

```yaml
- copy:
    src: /d/
    dest: /dest/d/
    mode: '0644'
    remote_src: true
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

---

The below details describe the case when you're not able to escalate to root on localhost. Given the file on localhost

```bash
shell> ll /tmp/test/d/f1
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Aug 25 23:23 /tmp/test/d/f1
```

the module *copy* works as expected

```yaml
- copy:
    src: /tmp/test/d/
    dest: /tmp/test/dest/
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

First, it tries to read the file and fails

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
> msg: 'an error occurred while trying to read the file ''/tmp/test/d/f1'': [Errno 13] Permission denied: b''/tmp/test/d/f1''. [Errno 13] Permission denied: b''/tmp/test/d/f1'''

By default, module *copy* copies files from *src* (local path to a file to copy to the remote server) to *dest* (remote absolute path where the file should be copied to). In this case, `become: true` means Ansible escalates privilege on the remote host, but not on the localhost master. Despite the fact that the task is running on localhost, i.e. both master and the remote host are localhost, without `remote_src: true` the setting `become: true` applies only to writing the file not to reading it. If you can't escalate to root on the localhost setting `remote_src: true`

```yaml
- copy:
    src: /tmp/test/d/
    dest: /tmp/test/dest/
    remote_src: true
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

will fail

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
> ansible_facts:
> discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3
> module_stderr: |-
> sudo: a password is required
> module_stdout: ''
> msg: |-
> MODULE FAILURE
> See stdout/stderr for the exact error
> rc: 1

---

Q: *"Is there any workaround for it?"*

A: Without the escalation to the root, there is no workaround. It would violate the ownership and permissions of the files. For example, given the file at the controller

```sh
shell> ll f1
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 18:17 f1
```

The playbook below was started by an unprivileged user

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01
  become: true
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: f1
        dest: /tmp
```

will crash

```yaml
TASK [copy] ****
fatal: [test_01]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'an error occurred while trying to read the file ''/scratch/f1'':
       [Errno 13] Permission denied: b''/scratch/f1'''
```

If you can't escalate to root on the localhost master the solution is to make the file readable for the user running the playbook.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: You're welcome. There shouldn't be any workaround to access root files without root permission.

Comment: @VladimirBotka This makes sense. But I also don't want all my other tasks to run as sudo (by running the playbook as sudo). Only those that have `become: yes`. So IIUC my options to 1. Change `src` file permissions or ownership with some `become: yes` task before the `copy` task (and restore original state again). 2. Specify for all other tasks to run as non-sudo somehow and run the playbook as sudo?

Comment: and 3. Use the `command` module as explained by OP.

Comment: @Carolus: only option 1 will work. I've updated the answer. Feel free to test other options and post your answer, or question with the code.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks. I opted for 1 myself. I changed owner (and group) of `src` to `{{ ansible_real_group_id }}`, copied my files with permission `mode: preserve` and then changed `src` owner (and group) back to root. This way I can restore the permissions of `src` to original state. In my case I didn't need the `dest` to belong to root, but I wanted to keep the permissions. I guess this doesn't merit a separate answer. And posting code to comments is difficult.

Comment: There actually is a simple workaround, just use `remote_src: true` on your `copy` module parameters. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: You're right. It wouldn't make sense to allow writing and deny reading when you can escalate. I updated the details. Thank you.

Comment: I hesitate to delete the answer completely. Feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Vladimir's answer, there actually IS a simple workaround!

The comment below (and the emphasis I added in bold) was the key.

> In the module copy, become: yes applies only to writing the file **not to reading it**.

Just use `remote_src: true`, even though you're copying the file locally. This causes the `become` to escalate privilege correctly when reading the `src` file/dir from the local machine because it treats the `src` as a remote machine and properly applies privilege escalation.

```yaml
- name: Copy Network
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  copy:
    src: /d/
    dest: "/dest/d/"
    remote_src: true  # this allows become to work as expected
    mode: 0644
  tags: [network]
```

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr - Ansible's `become: root` applies to the target machine, not to the Ansible host running the playbook. Workarounds are possible.*

I wrote an answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1771753/1015957) to address this problem for a single file: The Ansible host running the playbook doesn't raise it's own permissions to `root` with `become: root`; this only applies to the target machine. In the original question both are `localhost` but I think this behaviour still applies, think of it as a non-`root`-privileged 'source' and a `root`-privileged target.

The solution uses `delegate_to: localhost` to `slurp` the required file into memory - the `delegate_to:` enables `become: root` to work its magic locally, then write out the saved file to the target machine.

The original question asks about doing this for directories however: `slurp`ing directories has also been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292309/9624052) which should provide a suitable starting point when combined with the per-file `slurp` solution, esp. note @guzmonne's comment on that answer re. constructing a list of files to `slurp` before using the per-file workaround (which isn't great but may be preferable to altering file/directory permissions).