# Ansible error “ Could not find or access on Ansible Controller”

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to write an ansible playbook to send certificates to my client machines from my local machine. The error message I get is:

> msg": "Could not find or access '/etc/icinga2/pki/clienthostname.crt' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"

In the error output I also see this line:

> AnsibleFileNotFound(file_name=source, paths=[to_text(p) for p in search]) ansible.errors.AnsibleFileNotFound: Could not find or access '/etc/icinga2/pki/clienthostname.crt' on the Ansible Controller..\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"

I have added both the following to escalate my privileges but nothing has changed. I have also tried adding remote_src to my playbook like the error message suggested and although my playbook does compete without any errors the files are not actually copied over

> become: yes | become_user: root

Here is my playbook

```
name: Send client certificates
hosts: all
become: yes
become_user: root
vars:
        masternode: localhost
        clientnode: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
tasks:
         -name: Copy files to remote host
          connection: local
          become: yes 
          become_user: root
          copy:
                  src: /etc/icinga2/pki/{{ clientnode }}.crt
                  dest: /etc/icinga2/pki
```

I have confirmed that I am spelling the directory correctly and the file does exist. As a normal user I cannot access this directory as I get the Permission Denied error, so that is why I have added the become: yes and become_true to my playbook to elevate privileges but I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the key thing: @Zina comments on [another post](https://superuser.com/q/1619003/1015957) "*regarding become, it elevates privileges on the remote machine and not on the local*"

So the problem doesn't lie at the far end, it's at the local (Ansible Controller) end: This doesn't 'become' `root` and therefore can't read the file to copy. This issue affected me too, trying to copy across a locked-down SSH key file. My workaround is to `delegate_to: localhost` to `slurp` the file contents into a variable (it stores this in base64), then write this to the target host,

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    key_file: /etc/ssl/private/some.key
  tasks:

    - name: Copy webserver key file into memory
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        src: "{{ key_file }}"
      register: slurped_key_file
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Write copy of key file from memory
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        backup: true
        dest: "{{ key_file }}"
        group: root
        mode: 0600
        owner: root
        content: "{{ slurped_key_file['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

The trick here is that the `delegate_to: localhost` means that the local machine (Ansible controller) is treated as a remote machine for that stanza, and therefore `become:` is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give only below and try

```
src: {{ clientnode }}.crt
```

What I mean, the files which you want to be copied, if present at same location, don't give the full path.