# Ansible won't copy files from /etc directory but will from others (ansible.errors.AnsibleFileNotFound: Could not find or access)

Tags: linux, ansible

Ansible Version=2.7
I am trying to copy files from the local machines to a remote machine using an ansible playbook. The playbook is simple:

```
- name: Copy file to remote
  become: yes
  copy:
          src: /etc/directory/file.txt
          dest: /etc/directory
          mode: '0664'
```

This returns an error "ansible.errors.AnsibleFileNotFound: Could not find or access /etc/directory/file.txt" "Could not find or access '/etc/directory/file.txt' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"

So i tried changing this files permission to 777 and also changing the files owner and group but that didn't help. Then i copied this file out of the /etc directory into the home directory and the copy was successful. Why is this happening? I am using become: yes on the whole playbook to elevate my privilges as well so this error is confusing me.

Comment: well, looks like your user with whom you run the ansible playbook has no permissions to read that file (changing the file permissions is not always enough as the user needs read permission on the containing folder too), regarding become, it elevates privileges on the remote machine and not on the local.

Comment: So I have tried changing the ownership of the whole directory as well and that didn't help wither. Also I'm using become: yes on the whole playbook so i think that should elevate my privileges. I've run out of things to test currently.

Comment: again - [become is on the remote machine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/become.html) -> "Ansible allows you to ‘become’ another user, different from the user that logged into the machine **(remote user)**. This is done using existing privilege escalation tools such as sudo, su, pfexec, doas, pbrun, dzdo, ksu, runas, machinectl and others." and changing permissions of /etc or below is not encouraged - you should not change permission on system folders, sorry for not being clear on that.

Comment: [see this solution - AWX file copy cannot find local files and files copied to local don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699069/awx-file-copy-cannot-find-local-files-and-files-copied-to-local-dont-exist)

Comment: I've posted a solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1771753/1015957) that should address this problem (esp. in error message "Could not find or access '/etc/directory/file.txt' on the *Ansible Controller*."), if the issue is that the Ansible Controller has restrictive permissions on the file such that the user running Ansible can't access the file (but the root user can).